# What factors determine leveling up champion in league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Leveling up means not as leveling up the account level or ranking up but the "ingame" leveling up of the character. Most of the time I play LOL I noticed that despite having higher creep score than my opponent I am still underlevel. So it is certainly not the CS. 
Is it the damage dealt to champion that determines leveling up a champ?

Sorry but I didn't find it anywhere else with my search tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leveling up is based on being in range of the creep when it dies. You do not need to last hit it, as experience from minion deaths is split between all champions within 1400 range.

However, there are a number of reasons why they might be leveling faster than you:

- They might be using experience runes, which increase the amount of EXP they get.
- Their team has killed more towers, which grants team-wide experience.
- They have have been in range of more player kills, which are worth a lot more experience than ordinary minions.
- They might be leaving their lane in-between waves to kill jungle creeps.
- They might be in range of Zilean's experience increasing passive.

Comment: Nice answer, but to add: they don't actually have to score an assist or a kill to get the experience; just being in range of the death will grant exp.